# Firestore security rule get() not work

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

## The solution is in the end of the post. Check it out.

## Решение проблемы в конце поста. Дочитайте.

just a simple question: whats wrong with this and why this is not working?

Trying to get access with user who has role 'admin' in users section to the **/titles/{anyTitle}** but still get

> **Missing or insufficient permissions**.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow write: if false;
      allow read: if false;
    }
    function userCanWrite () {
      return get(/databases/{database}/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == "admin";
    }
    match /titles/{anyTitle=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if userCanWrite();
    }
  }
}
```

[Here is my database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j30cP.png)

### **P.S.**

I tried another rule from official documents
`get(/databases/{database}/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid‌​)).data.isAdmin == true;`

and this is not working too

## UPDATE: CORRECT WAY TO DO IT

Support helped me find the solution
this is how you should do:

**db structure:**

> users -> {{ userid }} -> { role: "admin" }

**database rule settings:**

> get(usersPath/$(request.auth.uid)).role == "admin" || get(usersPath/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == "admin";

Comment: he is dont care about it. Something wrong with get function.

Comment: (What `he` are you referring to?)

Comment: firestore security rules. He is dont care about ' or " or `. Im trying to restructure my users collection now. But im really confused why get(/da.../users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role is not really doc users/{uid}.role

Comment: `firestore security rules [don't] care about ' or " or \`` I was suggesting backticks as alternative markdown to make *Missing or insufficient permissions* stand out - `**` for **bold** works, too (obviously).

Comment: my eng is soooo bad. Im not understand everything you say to me :) sorry about that. But i tried another rule from official documents now get(/databases/{database}/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin == true; 
and this is not working too

Comment: *tried another rule from official documents now `get(/databases/{database}/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid‌​)).data.isAdmin == true`; and this is not working too* please edit additional information into your post - don't "hide" it in a comment.

Comment: I'm facing this error too. Maybe it's a firestore error?

Comment: already answered

Comment: Man, this is literally exactly what I'm trying to do. Unfortunately, the proposed solution does nothing... Anyone else not seeing this work?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I always get true no matter if my path or data is existing.
`get(/databases/$(database)/documents/crap).data.whatsoever == true `

Comment: This doesn't work for me. 2021 and the get() function is still broken

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I contacted to the Firebase support to report that bug and they gave me a temporary solution on this. It seems that they are having a bug in their systems on the security rules side. They say that the documentation is ok, but for now we should workaround this way:

```
get(path).data.field == true || get(path).field == true;
```

Because the bug is that data object isn't populated, you should check both properties. There's no ETA for launching a solution on this bug, so I asked they if they could give me an advice when they solved this issue, so I'll keep this answer up-to-date with their information.

Comment: Thanks, been fiddling with this issue for 2 days. Do you know if the same goes for the normal `resource` var. Does it become `resource.field` instead of `resource.data.field`?

Comment: @DarkNeuron Actually I don't know. I think this doesn't affect the resource var. If you try to access it with data and don't work, contact to google [firestore support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/)

Comment: @JoanPicornell any update on this one? I did I test today, and it seems like it works only with `get(path).data.field == true`

Comment: I posted : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73668342/firestore-security-rule-that-checks-field-under-random-document-in-collection-to . Did not get that tip, but I think I tried both without luck. They should update their docs at least, they are minimal at best and incomplete and sometimes wrong even. Great product but it needs some more love and maintenance.

Answer (score 5):

So the way I've solved it is I've created another `Collection` Called `admins`

Then I've just added the `uid` of the user I needed there as such -
 Here is my database structure - https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2YnN.png

And here is the rules

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function isAdmin() {
      return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/admins/$(request.auth.uid));
    }

    match /tasks/{anyTask} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
      allow update: if request.auth != null && isAdmin();
      allow delete: if request.auth != null && isAdmin();
    }
  }
}
```

You can view my full Open Source project here:
https://github.com/metaburn/doocrate

Comment: With pleasure @numfin If you can. please click on accept my answer.

Comment: it's not the right way to do =) Look at other answers

Comment: It feels more secure to create another collection `admins` then to have a sub field inside users (Some bug may give users the ability to update this field)

Comment: it feels more laggy

Comment: You will need to make sure users can't write and change this field so they would accidentally become admins.

Comment: You lose querying power if you move the object into a subcollection. You can no longer find users based on their role f.ex.

Comment: You create a new root collection. No need for subcollection

Answer (score 5):

You should use `$(database)` instead of `{database}` in your code:

```
get(/databases/{database}/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == "admin";
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. In this case I get the error `Function not found error: Name: [get].`

Comment: @colin not sure why you're getting this error. Some answer may be found in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55955938/function-not-found-error-name-get-in-firestore-security-rules-simulation

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was moving the `userCanWrite` function above my rules.  It appears that the function has to be defined before any of the `match` rules that call it. Maddening :-)

Comment: I read this and thought, wrong. I remember the documentation talking about hoisting. Plus, I have other functions that work that are defined below the matches. But no matter what I could not get my "get()" function to work until I tried this. It also works to just bump your function definitions to the same bracket scope as the match statements. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the Firestore rule I use to check if the user is admin.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {


match /{document=**} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow write: if userIsAdmin();
}


function userIsAdmin() {
    return getUserData().userRole == 'Admin';
}

function getUserData() {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/User/$(request.auth.uid)).data;
}

  }
}
```