# Basic firestore security rule: exists() working - why is get() not?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to validate a read in firestore, based on another document.

The data structure consists of 2 collections: "execution" and "test" .

In the test collection there is only 1 document, with the following id: SRJKCxU4HVDBdB3qyfzG, and theese values:

`admin true
id: "SRJKCxU4HVDBdB3qyfzG"
test: 1`

My security rules look like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function testFunction(testId) {
      // return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/test/$(testId));
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/test/$(testId)).data.id == "SRJKCxU4HVDBdB3qyfzG";
    }

    match /execution/{exeid} {
      allow read, write: if testFunction("SRJKCxU4HVDBdB3qyfzG");
    }

  }
}
```

If I use `return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/test/$(testId));` everything work's as expected. But no matter what I can't get this line to work `return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/test/$(testId)).data.id == "SRJKCxU4HVDBdB3qyfzG"`.

I really hope that I am missing simple and obvious? Any help is very common. I have also created a demo firebase project and stackblitz if necessary.

- Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-atfasp
- Firebase - send a pm.

Thanks for the help.

**Update - temporary solution**
Because of a firestore security rule bug, the data property is not populated. This will be fixed. The temporary solution for get() to work is the following:

`get(path).data.prop || get(path).prop`

Comment: I'm curious as to why you wouldn't just use `exists`?

Comment: the code is simplified. The real use case is to lookup a value on `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/test/$(testId))` and use this for validating.

Comment: Ah, okay. Using id as the example is likely misleading then since you should always be using exists for checking if a document exists. You can do both exists and get on the same document in a rule without it doing extra lookups (our system dedup these requests)

Answer (score 5):

`resource.id` doesn't exist yet, which is why you cannot do this.

Comment: I am not sure I follow you here? This document: `/databases/$(database)/documents/test/SRJKCxU4HVDBdB3qyfzG` certainly exists?

Comment: As a feature of the system. Get() returns a `resource` and we don't support id on this yet.

Comment: Ok sure enough. But I'm trying to retrieve a data property on the resource, called id. And this code `return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/test/$(testId)).data.id == "SRJKCxU4HVDBdB3qyfzG"` does not work as expected.

Comment: I'll have check our system tomorrow morning to see what's up there

Comment: I can add you to the test-firebase projected I created if you like? This test project and the stackblitz are the only moving parts :)

Comment: Thanks! I realized that I can use if(resource == null) to check if the resource exists or not in the firestore

Answer (score 4):

According to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46629170/firestore-security-rule-get-not-work), there is currently a bug in Firebase security rules:

> Because the bug is that data object isn't populated, you should check both properties. There's no ETA for launching a solution on this bug..

The temporary solution is to change the code to this:

`return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/test/$(testId)).id == "SRJKCxU4HVDBdB3qyfzG" || get(/databases/$(database)/documents/test/$(testId)).data.id == "SRJKCxU4HVDBdB3qyfzG"`

Comment: .id and data.id are different fields, so this is incorrect. data.id is a user defined field named id in a document rather than the id of a document.

Comment: let me just check this.

Comment: You can test it in the console. Create a new document, then add a field named id with a different value.

Comment: I follow you. But I can just observe that `get(path).data.prop` is not working as expected. I need this in the rule for it to work `get(path).prop || get(path).data.prop`

Comment: as noted in the other question, this is a bug that accords if you only use `get()` and don't have any other reference to `resource.data` or `request.resource.data` in your ruleset. We're working to fix it.