# In 2017 Firestore had a known bug on get(/databases/) function calls ... Has this been resolved now?

Tags: javascript, css, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Reading [this Stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664492/basic-firestore-security-rule-exists-working-why-is-get-not) about the **get(/databases/)** function call for Firestore security rules, it seems that a Firebase representative was explaining that the get(/databases/) call returns a 'resource' kind of value, and that at that time there was a bug on get(/databases/) calls so that the **.data** aspect of the call was not receiving data.

The post is dated October 2017.

Is this known bug still with us, does it explain why I have noticed difficulties receiving the expected result of a get(/databases/) function call, or has that bug since been resolved please?

If that bug still exists, is there an alternative way of reaching data within an alternative collection please?

With thanks.