# Allow read if property in document is in list of strings in token additional claims [Firestore]

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set rules in Firestore to allow a user access to a document only if a property in the document has a value contained in a list of strings. The list of strings is contained in the additional claims of the Firebase token generated by our python backend.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /myList/{itemId} {
        allow read: if resource.data.location_id in request.auth.token.locations
    }
  }
}
```

However, performing a query still returns all documents instead of only the ones where location_id is in the list we put in additional claims. I am not sure if this is related to [the bug mentioned in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46629170/firestore-security-rule-get-not-work) or if I have the syntax wrong in my Firestore rules.

My firestore structure looks like `myList/{itemId}/(item properties here, including location_id property which looks like location_id: "7")`

Here is the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#in_1) I am referencing to try to implement this rule.

Also, according to documentation,

> There are two operations for reads and queries in Cloud Firestore: get
>   and list. These correspond to the get() and where().get() (query),
>   methods in the client libraries. For your convenience, the read
>   operation allows both of these.

so specifying read should cover both these cases. I also used https://jwt.io/ to decode my firebase token to ensure the claims are being added correctly and it indeed shows inside my token

```
"claims": {
    "locations": [
      "6"
    ]
  },
```

**Edit:**
I have tried hard coding a single value like follows but I can't even get that to work, and it is still returning all documents.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /myList/{itemId} {
        allow read: if resource.data.location_id == '6'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that `in ['foo', 'bar']` is results in an implicit `OR` of conditions, which isn't currently supported as a query constraint.

At present you'll have to write a rule that makes this `OR` explicit:

```
// works fine for single gets
allow get: if resource.data.itemId in ['foo', 'bar']
// need to expand this for queries
allow list: if resource.data.itemId == 'foo' || resource.data.itemId == 'bar'
```

Comment: so `service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /myList/{itemId} {
      allow get: if resource.data.itemId in ['7']
      allow list: if resource.data.itemId == '7' || resource.data.itemId == '7'
    }
  }
}`?

Comment: If you only have a single item, you don't need to do `in ['7']` you can just use `== '7'`. Note that you'll want to ensure that you want `'7'` (the string) vs `7` (the number).