# Function not found error: Name: [get]. in firestore security rules simulation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

```
match /UserProfile {
    match /{uId}{
    allow get: if isUserLoggedIn() && !isUserBlocked(uId);
  }
```

when i try to get data from UserProfile/{uId} using the above security rules it throws the following error in the firestore and in code it says insufficient permissions:

```
Error running simulation — Error: simulator.rules line [199], column [28]. Function not found error: Name: [get].
```

now the definition of above two function are here

```
function isUserLoggedIn(){
    return request.auth != null;
}

function isUserBlocked(uId){
    return (('blocked' in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/UserSettings/$(uId)).data) && (request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/UserSettings/$(uId)).data.blocked));
}
```

the first function runs very well
but the second one doesn't

it throws that error

and as of my knowledge the function is alright

please help i have wasted a whole lot of time on this piddly problem

## what i have tried

1. i read in one of the threads that it is a temporary problem
   but it is not like that. its been more than 48 hours now
2. somewhere it was also mentioned that this is a bug only in simulator but the code will run smoothly and even this is not the case. in code the error is insufficient permissions as expected by me
3. i have read the docs properly so my code is alright  have tested the get method in other rules and there it is working fine

## thats it please help

Comment: Have you filed a bug for this? I'm seeing the same thing in my environment, not just in the simulator. Rules that have worked for months, and now suddenly don't.

Comment: @HondaGuy firebase devs already know about this. look at the comments of the accepted answer where Doug Stevenson himslef[he works for firebase] says devs knows about it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update: The errors are a bug in the rules simulator, see Doug's comment below.**

I tried out your rules and they worked as expected in the simulator.

Rules:

```
match /UserProfile {
  function isUserLoggedIn(){
    return request.auth != null;
  }

  function isUserBlocked(uId){
    return (('blocked' in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/UserSettings/$(uId)).data) && (request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/UserSettings/$(uId)).data.blocked));
  }

  match /{uId}{
    allow get: if isUserLoggedIn() && !isUserBlocked(uId);
  }
}
```

Test query in simulator:

```
get /UserProfile/foo
Authenticated: Yes
Firebase UID: bar
```

The request succeeds or fails based on the `UserSettings/foo` document in the database:

Denies request:

```
/UserSettings/foo    
{
 content: "my content"
 blocked: { bar: true }
}
```

Allows request:

```
/UserSettings/foo    
{
 content: "my content"
 blocked: { otheruser: true }
}
```

I think that errors can pop up when the data doesn't exist or isn't in the expected format.

For example, if I delete the `/UserSettings/foo` document I also receive:

```
Error: simulator.rules line [58], column [28]. Function not found error: Name: [get].
```

I also get this error if the `blocked` field is anything other than a map (because `in` is a function for maps):

```
Error: simulator.rules line [58], column [95]. Function not found error: Name: [in].
```

You can probably clean up these errors by using `exists` and checking the type of `blocked` but either way, your rules should still deny the request as expected.

Comment: I would call this a bug in the simulator, as a non-existent document shouldn't yield an error like that.  But it should fail the rule though.

Comment: Confirmed with the team - it is a bug in the simulator.

Comment: big thanks to both
well
this answer is fine 
actually that's the case
yesterday only i discovered that this error appears on fields which do not exist and the simulator should throw an error like 'field does not exist' but it say 'method not found' and this thing wasted so much time

Comment: @DougStevenson
juan [unable to tag him] lol
please read the above comment

Comment: I tried to work around this error (make it work in simulator) this way: `function isAdmin() {  return isAuth() && exists(/database/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)) && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true; }` but adding the `exists()` call makes the simulator give "unknown error".

Comment: Seems like this bug is still not fixed after more than two years

Comment: It is indeed a bug in the simulator (that is there up until today). If the data you try to get does not exist, rather than saying the rule is rejected it throws an error. Very lame and time consuming